# Format cell based on formula value

Tags: excel, vba

I have cells with data `Peer(3)`

I get the number with `VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(F2,2)))`

then I want to give the cell a color I am trying with but not working I get type mismatch, been trying for couple of hours and getting no where.

Thanks

```
Sub Format()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheets("sheet1")

LastRow = WS.range("F" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If WS.range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=Value(Left(Right(F2, 2)))" < 3 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10

End Sub
```

Comment: where your `cell` variable refers to? describe your problem more- what is `Peer(3)`, where, etc... there are few mistakes in your code and it's not clear which way we could give you advice as your final goal is unclear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Sub Format()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
dim rCell as range

Set WS = Sheets("sheet1")

LastRow = WS.range("F" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

for each rcell in WS.range("F2:F" & LastRow).cells
 if clng(Left(Right(rcell.value, 2), 1)) < 3 Then rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Josie, thanks for your response.  I am not by my computer till later this evening, I will try your code then and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VBA, use Conditional Formatting.

for e.g.
Say your cells from F1 to F10 contain values such as Peer(2), Peer(3), Peer(1) etc

1. Select the Range F1 to F10 (or to any cell which you want formatted)
2. On the ribbon, click on "Conditional Formatting" -> "New Rule"
3. Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Assuming the active cell is F1, type in the formula `=VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(F1,2))) < 3`
5. Click on "Format" button, go to "Fill" tab, click on "More Colors", "Custom" tab.
6. Put 128 for Green, 0 for Red and Blue.
7. Click "OK" till the dialog closes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello Shahklpesh thanks for your response. I have to use vba as the workbook is created dynamically.

Comment: @Tim: You can do the above in VBA too. Record a macro for the above steps, modify it for your needs and make it part of your dynamic workbook creation. Cheers.