# Test for Null in IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I got the sub below from: [Format cell based on formula value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904332/format-cell-based-on-formula-value) from "JosieP"

I am trying to test for Null cells as the sub fails if it encounters one. If it encounters a null cell I want to add a color to the cell

`If IsNull(rCell) Then rCell.Interior.Color = 8` does not work but does not fail either.

`if clng(Left(Right(rcell.value, 2), 1)) < 3 Then rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10` fails when there is a null cell .

I tried adding Not IsNull(rCell) so I would have
`if clng(Left(Right(rcell.value, 2), 1)) < 3 And Not IsNull(rCell) Then rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10` but this fails as well.

```
Sub Format()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
dim rCell as range

Set WS = Sheets("sheet1")

LastRow = WS.range("F" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

for each rcell in WS.range("F2:F" & LastRow).cells

 If IsNull(rCell) Then rCell.Interior.Color = 8

if clng(Left(Right(rcell.value, 2), 1)) < 3 And Not IsNull(rCell) Then rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10

next rcell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell values in Excel never contain the `Null` value. If the cell is blank, it is `Empty`.

```
If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then ...
```

Also, a cell that is blank is different from a cell that contains an empty string (zero-length string). To test for those, you use

```
If Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then ...
```

Note that unlike `IsEmpty`, this is not protected from a type mismatch error. If your cell happens to contain an error value (e.g. `#N/A`), you will get a runtime error 13: Type mismatch when trying to check its length. To be extra safe, you may want to check for `IsError(rCell.Value)` first.

Comment: Hello GSerg, `If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then` worked. So I tried `If CLng(Left(Right(rCell.Value, 2), 1)) <3 And Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then rCell.Interior.Color = 10` but it fails after it encounters a empty cell

Comment: @Tim Because you are trying to convert a value to `Long` before making sure it is eligible. VBA does not short-circuit, so you have to first check `If Len(rCell.Value) > 0`, then, as a nested if, check `If CLng(Left(Right(rCell.Value, 2), 1)) < 3`. You may also want to add yet another nested `If` in between of those two, to see `If IsNumeric(Left(Right(rCell.Value, 2), 1))`.

Comment: I got it `If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
  rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
  
ElseIf Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then

If CLng(Left(Right(rCell.Value, 2), 1)) =<3 Then rCell.Interior.Color = 3407769 End IF`.  Thank you