# Type Mismatch Error in Worksheet_Change Event

Tags: vba, excel

The code below checks for:

- duplicate entry in column 1 & restricts them
- then performs validation to ensure user can only input value BATCH[0-9]_[0-9] in first column

I am getting the following error for second block of code

> error -Runtime error 13 Type mismatch

on the line `-If Not Target.Value Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then`

Would appreciate if anyone can help fix this error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, msg As String, x As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Columns(1), Target)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each r In rng
If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
If Application.CountIf(Columns(1), r.Value) > 1 Then
msg = msg & vbLf & r.Address(0, 0) & vbTab & r.Value
If x Is Nothing Then
                    r.activate
                    Set x = r
                Else
                    Set x = Union(x, r)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Len(msg) Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate values not allowed Invalid Entry" & msg
        x.ClearContents
        x.Select
   End If
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set x = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    'check if format is valid BATCH00_00
    If Not Target.Value Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
            MsgBox "Invalid format!"
        GoTo ValidationError
        Exit Sub
    End If
      Exit Sub
ValidationError:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

sample data in spread sheet

yes I do have data in my spread sheet

```
Batch_Code  |   Batch_Name  |   Batch_Invoker_Name
BATCH00_01  |   DwhEtl_MetaData_Loading start   |   Invalid
BATCH00_02  |   DwhEtl_MetaData_Loading |   dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_03  |   DwhEtl_MetaData_Loading1111 |   dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_04  |   DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R22213123  |   dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_05  |   DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131312 |   dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_06  |   DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131313 |   dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_07  |   DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131314 |   dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_08  |   DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131315 |   dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_09  |   DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131316 |


with Batch_Code  as column 1 to be validated & checked with
```

--Also I have tried the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim validationError Boolean
    validationError = False
    'if changed cell was not in A column, then exit sub
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    'check if format is valid BATCH00_00
    If Not Target.Value Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid format!"
        validationError = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'check for uniqueness in A column
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Target.Value) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Values must be unique in A column!"
        validationError = True
    End If

    If validationError Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And this one:

```
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If IsError(Target.Column) Then
    'check if format is valid BATCH00_00
    If Not Target.Column Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
            MsgBox "Invalid format!"
        GoTo ValidationError
        Exit Sub
    End If
     End If
      Exit Sub
ValidationError:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above mine should be marked correct.

Using code and input copied directly from the OP and running results in expected behavior.  Duplicate entries and invalid format's return expected messages.  Further testing reveals that the OP's problem is exactly as described in the question above.  This is verified by creating an error in Column A with the formula "=5/0".  The returned error, as properly diagnosed in the answer is a run time error, type mismatch.

The OP has clearly not investigated the avenue suggested to him.

Here is a the code I used to test, the only material change would be adding option explicit, debug.print output to test branching, 1 comment line, and putting 1 declaration to a line.  No other changes except white space.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim msg As String
    Dim x As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Columns(1), Target)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rng
            If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
                If Application.CountIf(Columns(1), r.Value) > 1 Then
                    msg = msg & vbLf & r.Address(0, 0) & vbTab & r.Value
                    If x Is Nothing Then
                        r.Activate
                        Set x = r
                    Else
                        Set x = Union(x, r)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Len(msg) Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate values not allowed Invalid Entry" & msg
            x.ClearContents
            x.Select
        End If
        Set rng = Nothing
        Set x = Nothing
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    'check if format is valid BATCH00_00
    If Not Target.Value Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid format!"
        GoTo ValidationError
Debug.Print "should never be run"
        Exit Sub    'what's the point of this ?
    End If
Debug.Print "normal exit"
    Exit Sub

ValidationError:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Debug.Print "exit from validation error"
End Sub
```

This is the sample input.  Remove the Div/0 error and the program runs.

```
Batch_Code  Batch_Name  Batch_Invoker_Name
BATCH00_01  DwhEtl_MetaData_Loading start   Invalid
BATCH00_02  DwhEtl_MetaData_Loading dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_03  DwhEtl_MetaData_Loading1111 dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_04  DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R22213123  dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_05  DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131312 dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_06  DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131313 dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_07  DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131314 dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_08  DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131315 dwhetl_batch_meta_load.unx
BATCH00_09  DwhEtl_Reg_Files_R323131316 
BATCH10_10      
#DIV/0!
```

Comment: *it can be null but i am pretty sure it can't be empty.*
Give it a try:  https://pastebin.com/HesR3wP0

Comment: If i was at my computer then I would have tested before responding... hence the somewhat ambiguous language.  I'm guessing it does work or you wouldn't have sent the link.  Carrying further, if r.value is null then we know r is not nothing and r is not empty, looking at your answer, if r.value is empty then... can r be nothing or not empty?   it seems like that would make sense, if r is not empty but r. value is empty then r holds an error..... alas, i can't test for a few hours  :(

Comment: It is the opposite. `Range.Value` can be `Empty`, but [it is never `Null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944546/11683). `Range`, on the other hand, can be neither `Null` nor `Empty`, it can only be `Nothing`. The reason why `IsEmpty(r)` even works is because it [actually calls `IsEmpty(r.Value)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683).

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious  can u help me fix this code please

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now so i can't test code but i'll certainly try to help.  with your sample data, what should the current program output be (if it was working)?   have you resolved the out of memory error?

Comment: Thanks, @ProfoundlyOblivious
The output should only allow user to enter values liked BATCH##_## E.G BATCH01_02 ,BATCH01_99 and make sure that these values are not repeated .. while the validation rule works ..im getting bounced between type mismatch & out of memory error for the BATCH##_## part

Comment: out of memory is likely from runaway recursion or performing some tasks with really big ranges.  you could try finding the last used cell in the column so you can work with a much smaller range (instead of the whole column) to see if the memory error goes away.  I'm assuming you have data you're testing with, not an empty spreadsheet.  and that you have a result that the program should match.  be it duplicate values not allowed, invalid format, or no output (success)... with your test data, what is the expected output.

Comment: yes I do have data in my spread sheet @ProfoundlyOblivious I have edited my question & added what the sample data looks like.it is a very small subset of data in first column with hardly 10 entries

Comment: in the other example codes you said you tried, do you get the same error or is it different?  with the sample data you presented, it looks valid, so your program should complete without any messages?

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious im getting same error of type mismatch on all the codes not sure what is wrong :(

Comment: on the error line, If Not Target.Value Like "BATCH[0-9].... try replacing "not"  with "false =" so it reads If false = Target.Value Like "BATCH[0-9][....

Comment: I'm thinking vba is trying to evaluate not before it performs like, if is, that would explain the error... or i could be flat wrong

Comment: nope, that's not it   just looked it up   you're fine the way it is

Comment: I'll have to get on the plane, but the good news is I'll have access to a computer when i get back home.  I'm stumped right now but I'll try running the code if this isn't solved by then

Comment: Dude - next time, follow the advice that's given.  Your problem was solved within 15 minutes of your post and you did nothing more but waste time from that point on.  Congratulations!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177570/discussion-between-profoundlyoblivious-and-sshitanshu).

Answer (score 1):

The error comes, because the `Target.Value` is some kind of an error. Thus, an error cannot be compared with anything and it throws this Type Mismatch Error. Try this piece of code to replicate:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Range("A1") = "=6 / 0" 'Making a #DIV/0! to replicate
    If Range("A1") Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
        Debug.Print "SOMETHING"
    End If

End Sub
```

Thus, in your code, the easiest you can do is to sanitize the input somehow. E.g., check whether it is not an error. This is easily done with the `IsError()` function:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Range("A1") = "=6 / 0"
    If Not IsError(Range("A1")) Then
        If Range("A1") Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
            Debug.Print "SOMETHING"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Thus, in your original code, try the following:

```
If Not IsError(Target) Then
    If Not Target.Value Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid format!"
        GoTo ValidationError
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @Sshitanshu - write `If IsError(Target.Value) Then` before the line with the error.

Comment: If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    'check if format is valid BATCH00_00
    If IsError(Target.value) Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Target.value Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
            MsgBox "Invalid format!"
        GoTo ValidationError
    End If
     End If
       Exit Sub
ValidationError:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.value = vbNullString
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: @Sshitanshu - give it a try with F8 to see where you are getting the error - https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-step-through-a-macro-in-Excel

Comment: I appended the code with :    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsError(Target.value) Then
    'check if format is valid BATCH00_00
    If Target.value Like "BATCH[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]" Then
            MsgBox "Invalid format!"
        GoTo ValidationError
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
      Exit Sub
ValidationError:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub   

im getting same error or a out of memory error

Comment: @Sshitanshu - it is tough to follow the code in the comments, because it is not formatted. It is a good idea to show what you have tried in the question.

Comment: apologize @Vityata I have edited my question you can check the code used in that

Comment: I tried that too but its evaluating to a type mismatch error @Vityata

Comment: I just used the experience you gave me here for another answer with Type Mismatch.... you sir, did not give me a fish, instead you gave me a rod and line with a hook then pointed to a section of the the lake and said "you go there, catch heap big fish"

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious - thanks again for appreciating it! :)