# Runtime error 13. Userform does not accept null values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to feed the cell values to and from the userform called `calcform`. In doing so, the run command gives an error if the values are empty. Other than giving conditional statements to each of the values, what are the other possibilities?

```vb
Private Sub cancalc_Click()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sysbal")
        .Activate
        .Range("C1").Value = calcform.customercan.Text
        .Range("C2").Value = calcform.phonecan.Text
        .Range("C3").Value = calcform.faxcan.Text
        .Range("C4").Value = calcform.attentioncan.Text
         calcform.fromcan.Text = "-"
         calcform.phonecanme.Text = "-"
         calcform.faxcanme.Text = "-"
         .Range("L17").Value = CLng(calcform.condtempcan.Text)
         .Range("L18").Value = CLng(calcform.subcoolingcan.Text)
         .Range("L19").Value = CLng(calcform.entfluidcan.Text)
         .Range("L20").Value = CLng(calcform.btuhtdcan.Text)
         .Range("L33").Value = CLng(calcform.dischargecan.Text)
         .Range("L34").Value = CLng(calcform.suctioncan.Text)
         .Range("E9").Value = calcform.modelcan.Text
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sysbal")
        .Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        calcform.facevelocitycan.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E23").Value, 0))
        calcform.relativehumiditycan.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E26").Value, 2))
        calcform.subcoolingareacan.Text = CStr(Round(.Range("E28").Value, 0))
        calcform.refpredropcan.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E31").Value, 0))
        calcform.airfrictioncan.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E32").Value, 0))
        calcform.subcoolcan.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E33").Value, 0))
        calcform.exitvelocity.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E34").Value, 0))
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: Cell values are [never `Null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944546/11683), but can be `Empty`. Which line causes the error?

Comment: @GSerg Yes sometimes dichargecan.text can be empty or sometimes entfluid.text can be empty. It depends on the calculation. However, excel should accept empty values.

Comment: It does. On which line do you have the error?

Comment: @GSerg I had an error in line 11 (`.range("L17").value = CLang(calcform.condtempcan.Text)`) but I removed CLng and now new error occurs at line 23. (`calcform.facevelocity...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is if a TextBox is empty, then `calcform.entfluidcan.Text` returns an empty string `""`. And if you try to convert an empty string into a `Long` using `CLng` it errors.

So you need to check first if the value in the text box is numeric:

```
If IsNumeric(calcform.entfluidcan.Text) Then 
    .Range("L19").Value = CLng(calcform.entfluidcan.Text)
Else
    .Range("L19").Value = 0
End If
```

---

Also the following line will error

```
calcform.facevelocitycan.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E23").Value, 0))
```

if the value in `.Range("E23").Value` is not a number. Also check first if is numeric.

```
If IsNumeric(.Range("E23").Value) Then 
    calcform.facevelocitycan.Caption = CStr(Round(.Range("E23").Value, 0))
Else
    calcform.facevelocitycan.Caption = "NaN"
End If
```

---

Example for using it with a function:

```
Public Function ConvertToLong(ByVal InputValue As Variant) As Long
    ConvertToLong = 0 'default if it cannot be converted

    If IsNumeric(InputValue) Then 
        ConvertToLong = CLng(InputValue)
    End If
End Function
```

Alternatively

```
Public Function ConvertToLong(ByVal InputValue As Variant) As Long
    ConvertToLong = 0 'default if it cannot be converted
    On Error Resume Next 'let it try to convert if it errors it will stay default
    ConvertToLong = CLng(InputValue)
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

and use it like:

```
.Range("L19").Value = ConvertToLong(calcform.entfluidcan.Text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It becomes very tedious process to write the conditional statement for all the conditions. The values here are just a small portion of other a huge form. Is using "procedures" the answer?

Comment: @user9909958 use functions not procedures for that. See my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.